# MySQL syntax for displaying many-to-many db results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, syntax, many-to-many

I have created a many-to-many db like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Films (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY(id),    
Title VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Ambiences (  
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
PRIMARY KEY(id),  
ambienceName VARCHAR(255));

CREATE TABLE Films_Ambiences (
film_id INT NOT NULL,  
ambience_id INT NOT NULL,  
PRIMARY KEY (film_id, ambience_id),  
FOREIGN KEY (film_id) REFERENCES Films(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE,  
FOREIGN KEY (ambience_id) REFERENCES Ambiences(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Now: I have inserted some data and joined the tables to get:

```
╔════════╦════╦══════════╗  
║ Title  ║ id ║ Ambience ║  
╠════════╬════╬══════════╣  
║ film_1 ║  1 ║ Funny    ║
║ film_1 ║  1 ║ Sad      ║
║ film_2 ║  2 ║ Funny    ║
║ film_2 ║  2 ║ Sad      ║
╚════════╩════╩══════════╝
```

However, my aim is to displaying film_1 in one row and film_2 in second row, like this:

```
╔════════╦════╦══════════╗  
║ Title  ║ id ║ Ambience ║  
╠════════╬════╬══════════╣  
║ film_1 ║  1 ║ Funny,Sad║
║ film_2 ║  2 ║ Funny,Sad║
╚════════╩════╩══════════╝
```

I am trying to use `GROUP_CONCAT` but instead i get:

```
╔════════╦════╦════════════════════════╗
║ Title  ║ id ║        Ambience        ║
╠════════╬════╬════════════════════════╣
║ film_1 ║  1 ║ funny, funny, sad, sad ║
╚════════╩════╩════════════════════════╝
```

it merges all rows into a single one.
Here is an **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b70/2)** for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(ambienceName SEPARATOR ' ') AS ambiences
FROM   Films AS f 
   INNER JOIN Films_Ambiences as fa
         ON f.id = fa.film_id           
   INNER JOIN Ambiences AS a
         ON a.id = fa.ambience_id
GROUP  BY title
```

[Updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17b70/3)

Result is:

```
TITLE   AMBIENCES
film1   sad happy
film2   sad happy
```

Comment: Well that was easy :D. Thanks for help @mishik!